# how to authenticate azure key vault using client id and secret?

Tags: node.js, azure-keyvault

I have a azure key vault and i am trying to get the secret from that vault and print it in console in node js. This is the code i got from documentation,

```
const { DefaultAzureCredential} = require("@azure/identity");
const { SecretClient } = require("@azure/keyvault-secrets");

const credential = new DefaultAzureCredential();

// Build the URL to reach your key vault
const vaultName = "web-designer";
const url = `https://${vaultName}.vault.azure.net`;

// Lastly, create our secrets client and connect to the service
const client = new SecretClient(url, credential);

const secretName = "web-designer-secret";

client.getSecret(secretName).then((res)=>{
    console.log(res);
}).catch((err)=>{
    console.log("error",err);
})
```

Here they are using DefaultAzurecredential to validate account. But instead of that i want to use client id and client secret to validate my key vault. How to do this without DefaultAzureCredential?

I tried ManagedIdentityCredential but not working.

Comment: use [`ClientSecretCredential`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-js/blob/main/sdk/identity/identity/README.md#authenticate-service-principals)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reproducing from my end, I could able to achieve Authentication using `ClientSecretCredential` following the below code.

```
const { ClientSecretCredential } = require("@azure/identity");
const { SecretClient } = require("@azure/keyvault-secrets");

const credential = new ClientSecretCredential("<TENANTID>","<CLIENTID>","<CLIENTSECRET>");

const vaultName = "<VAULTNAME>";
const url = `https://${vaultName}.vault.azure.net`;

const client = new SecretClient(url, credential);

const secretName = "<SECRETNAME>";

client.getSecret(secretName).then((res)=>{
    console.log(res);
}).catch((err)=>{
    console.log("error",err);
})
```

**RESULTS:**

[image]